# Prove of inverse of function is sigma algebra in measurable space

Tags: measure-theory

Let R be a set and (S; B) be a measurable space. Let X : R -> S be a function. Show that the collection of all subsets of R given in f={Inverse of X(A) : A belongs to B} is a sigma algebra.

I can prove for countable union and intersection condition. But not able to solve other conditions for sigma algebra.

Not a homework. Part of book exercise I am trying to solve.

Comment: Which "other conditions for sigma algebra" do you have problem with?

Comment: The empty and full set conditions , those I couldn't comprehend.